# Convert string to bytes literally

Tags: string, python-3.x, encoding, byte

I want to take a string such as:

```
'\\xeb\\x4d'
```

and turn it into:

```
b'\xeb\x4d'
```

If I do:

```
bytes('\\xeb\\x4d', 'utf-8')
```

I get:

```
b'\\xeb\\x4d'
```

I need something that does the following:

```
something('\\xeb\\x4d') == b'\xeb\x4d'
```

Comment: Is your input `'\\xeb\\x4d'` or `'\xeb\x4d'`?  You use both in the body of your question.

Comment: My input is `'\\xeb\\x4d'`. I edited my question acordingly. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = '\\xeb\\x4d'   # a Unicode string
>>> a.encode('latin1') # get a byte string
b'\\xeb\\x4d'
>>> a.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape') # unescape, get a Unicode string
'ëM'
>>> a.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1') # get a byte string
b'\xebM'
>>> a.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1') == b'\xeb\x4d'
True
```

Note that `latin1` is the first 256 codepoints of Unicode, so encoding the first 256 bytes of Unicode gives the same byte values as the original codepoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark. The explanation about the latin1 codec helped me understand what is exactly going on !

Answer (score 1):

```
a = '\\xeb\\x4d'
a = bytes(a, 'utf-8')
a = a.decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1')
```

gives

```
b'\xebM'
```

because

```
'\x4d' == 'M'
```

Comment: You can directly encode with `latin1` ,`'\xeb\x4d'.encode('latin1')`

Comment: My original string has escaped backslashes, that's why I need to decode with the 'unicode_escape' codec.